# Download Versions of a SharePoint 2007 Document?

Tags: 2007, development, document-library, powershell

Can anyone point me in the direction of downloading all the versions of a file in a SharePoint 2007 document library?

Is this possible with PowerShell, C#, or another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the different file versions by keeping the folder structure as well:

```
private long AccessFolder(SPFolder folder)
{

    string strPath = string.Empty;

    long lFolderSize = 0;

    if (m_strExportDir != string.Empty) {
        strPath = folder.ServerRelativeUrl;
    }

    int iTotalVersions = 0;
    int iI = 0;
    string FinalFileName = "";
    DateTime dt_SPFileCreated = default(DateTime);
    string s_FileName = "";

    foreach (SPFile file in folder.Files) {
        iTotalVersions = file.Versions.Count;
        SPFileVersionCollection versions = file.Versions;
        for (iI = 0; iI <= iTotalVersions - 1; iI++) {
            iTotalDocs = iTotalDocs + 1;
            SPFileVersion version = versions(iI);
            // Dim hash As System.Collections.Hashtable = _
            file.Versions(iI).Properties();
            // Dim keys As System.Collections.ICollection = hash.Keys
            s_FileName = file.Name;
            dt_SPFileCreated = file.Versions(iI).Created;
            m_iTotalFileVersions += 1;              
            FinalFileName = file.name;
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Pathtofilesystemtosave + "\\Revision-" + m_iTotalFileVersions.ToString);
            string sFileLoc = path + "\\Revision-" + m_iTotalFileVersions.ToString + "\\\\" + FinalFileName;
            byte[] binFile = version.OpenBinary();
            if (binFile.Length > 0) {
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(sFileLoc, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
                fs.Write(binFile, 0, binFile.Length);
                fs.Close();
            }
        }

        // Now for current file
        iI = iI + 1;
        iTotalDocs = iTotalDocs + 1;
        System.Collections.Hashtable hash = file.Properties;
        System.Collections.ICollection keys = hash.Keys;
        s_FileName = file.Name;
        dt_SPFileCreated = file.TimeCreated;

        FinalFileName = file.Name;
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Pathtofilesystemtosave + "\\Revision-" + iI.ToString());
        string sFileLoc = Path + "\\Revision-" + iI.ToString() + "\\\\" + FinalFileName;
        byte[] binFile = file.OpenBinary();
        if (binFile.Length >= 0) {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(sFileLoc, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
            fs.Write(binFile, 0, binFile.Length);
            fs.Close();
        }
    }
}
```