# Get all the versions of files and metadata from a MOSS 2007 document library

Tags: 2007, document-library, metadata, version-history

Is there a best practise to get all document versions with metadata from 2007 doc lib on Windows Server 2003?

data is **not** migrated to another SharePoint! It will be transfered to other platform and has to be exported to file system.

search result so far:

[codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20614/Download-all-the-versions-of-a-file-from-a-SharePo)

[StackExchange](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/38945/download-versions-of-a-sharepoint-2007-document)